# How can accessing super in an instance method cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management

Inside an instance method I'm calling the same selector on the superclass and getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I'm using manual reference counting (not ARC), and this is happening in the main thread. Static analysis reports no issues, not that I take that to mean a clean bill of health. The relevant code is as follows:

CommentListMedia.m (stack frame 1 in the trace below):

```
- (void)play {
  if ((comments.isLoading) && (! comments.isLoaded)) 
    playWhenLoaded = YES;
  else [super play]; // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens here
}
```

MediaControls.m (stack frame 2 in the trace below):

```
- (void)play {
  [media play]; // <-- this calls the code above
  [self notifyWithName:MediaControlsDidPlayNotification];
}
```

MyApp.m (stack frame 11 in the trace below):

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [super sendEvent:event]; // <-- this calls the code above
  ...
}
```

The superclass of CommentListMedia is SequentialMedia, which doesn't figure into the stack trace because the exception occurs before it's reached.

Unfortunately I'm only seeing this in crash reports (from Crashlytics), and haven't been able to reproduce it myself.  What strikes me as odd about it is that the reference to the class instance must have been good to perform the play selector in the first place, but somehow by the time it gets to the end, the reference to the superclass is bad. At first I thought the instance might be auto-released or something, but I'm under the impression that autoreleasing happens on the main thread at the end of the run loop, not at some random time in the middle of a call.  Any input on what might be causing this or how to debug it would be appreciated.

The call stack on the main thread looks like this:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib   objc_msgSend + 5
1   MyApp             -[CommentListMedia play]
2   MyApp             -[MediaControls play]
3   UIKit             -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
4   UIKit             -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
5   UIKit             -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
6   UIKit             -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
7   UIKit             -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
8   UIKit             -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
9   UIKit             -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 832
10  UIKit             -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
11  MyApp             -[MyApp sendEvent:]
12  UIKit             _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7096
13  CoreFoundation    __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
14  CoreFoundation    __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
15  CoreFoundation    __CFRunLoopRun + 622
16  CoreFoundation    CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
17  CoreFoundation    CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
18  GraphicsServices  GSEventRunModal + 138
19  UIKit             UIApplicationMain + 1136
20  MyApp             main
```

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting the stack trace here, namely I don't understand how did you come to the conclusion that something is wrong with the 'super' reference. From this stack trace, the only thing I see is that the _play_ method is sent to CommentListMedia class, I can only assume that MediaControls is inheriting from CommentListMedia. It would be useful if you added your class hierarchy in the description + play method in both classes.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from a crash?

Comment: @lawicko I edited out the line numbers from the stack trace, since they don't mean much for a code snippet, but I've marked the line given for item 1 on the stack with a comment in the code snippet.  I've included snippets for the other class as well and clarified the hierarchy.

Comment: @RyanR I did post a stack trace; is there something additional you're looking for?

Comment: That is the stack trace from an exception report?

Comment: My money is on the exception report giving you a slightly incorrect line number as a result of code optimization in the release build. I think the real exception is happening 2 lines above where you're checking properties on the comments object.

Comment: Ok, good that you posted the code, there is one more piece missing, we need to know the entire inheritance chain from the CommentListMedia class to NSObject. Also all the _play_ methods. I don't exactly buy the "exception occurs before it's reached" argumentation, you need to be more careful when assuming things here ;) *Edit* after reading RyanR comment, I think he might actually be right, check this trace too.

Comment: @RyanR It's a stack trace of the main thread from Crashlytics, slightly sanitized and edited into a text-friendly format.  I wish I could make this crash happen in XCode, but it seems to result from a unique set of circumstances which I haven't been able to reproduce.

Comment: @RyanR Yes, the line numbers being off was also something I had considered.  I was hoping maybe someone with experience with Crashlytics would chime in with an opinion on how accurate their symbolication is.

Comment: @JesseCrossen I beleive Crashlytics uses the same symbolication tools as Xcode (mostly because nobody else has created a toolchain for modern obj-c except apple), and since I get the *wonderful* incorrect line numbers from optimized code pretty regularly... I would try to force the situation locally to reproduce it - look at what code paths mutate the `comments` object (or whatever objects it encapsulates and uses in those two properties) and modify code to intentionally set them to edge case values (just for debugging)

Comment: @RyanR Yeah, here's what they say about it (probably a good dose of hype in there): "The Crashlytics SDK uses a multi-step symbolication process to provide progressively higher levels of detail. We start with on-device symbolication. Once a crash report makes it into our system, stack frames are then re-processed against your application's dSYM on our servers. This two-step symbolication process, coupled with our advanced aggregation algorithms, provides the highest information fidelity available."

Comment: If RyanR is right, it's likely to be a very subtle reference counting error somewhere in more than 25K lines of code, which could be tricky to find. What I might do is break the code up a little more so the stack trace has less scope for ambiguity.  If it's still pointing at the call to super, I'll come back to this question, but it's going to be at least a week before the new code is in the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib   objc_msgSend + 5
1   MyApp             -[CommentListMedia play]
```

That *may* be a crash in `-[SequentialMedia play]`.   Specifically, if that method returns `void` and makes a call as the last expression in the method, it may be that the [optimizing] compiler generated a tail call.  This would effectively cause the method call to disappear from the stack.

Post the contents of the registers from your crash report.  $r0 can be quite illuminating (as it is the first arg and should be a viable object).

Also, if there is heavy concurrency in play in your program, then it could be that the object is being released and deallocated by a secondary thread.   But, typically, you would see more than one flavor of odd crash (though sometimes not, if your code makes heavy use of synchronization primitives -- it can be remarkable how consistent a concurrent program behaves from run to run).

Comment: This is really intriguing, and exactly the kind of debugging tip I'm looking for.  Unfortunately Crashlytics doesn't seem to give me the register values and so far I've never seen any crash reports in iTunes Connect either (no surprise there).  But anyway, [SequentialMedia play] does return void and under some conditions does end with a call, so I'm going to pursue that route and see where it takes me.

Comment: @JesseCrossen It may lead nowhere, but, when debugging these kinds of infuriating problems, even a weak straw to grasp at is better than no straws at all.

Comment: It's a much stronger straw than anything else I had. :) I'm going to mark this as the answer because your explanation of the trace results answers my question about how a super call can appear to be the cause of a crash. Following your lead also turned up some potential problems and fixes, but I won't know whether they work until the app update is approved sometime next week.

Comment: Thanks! Your intuition turned out to be correct. I still haven't fixed the bug, but at least now I know what sort of thing is being over-released.